Pydantic BaseModel validation order for Json vs str
Can someone tell me why Pydantic is validating a field as a string even though the field type is Json[Any] | str? And is there a way to have it return a dict instead?
from typing import Any

from pydantic import BaseModel, Json


class FooStr(BaseModel):
    json_or_str: Json[Any] | str


class FooInt(BaseModel):
    json_or_int: Json[Any] | int


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(type(FooStr(json_or_str='{"a": 1}').json_or_str))  # prints <class 'str'>
    print(type(FooInt(json_or_int='{"a": 1}').json_or_int))  # prints <class 'dict'>


How do you think it should validate instead, and why?

I think
type(FooStr(json_or_str='{"a": 1}').json_or_str)

should be a dict because Json[Any] is the first type in json_or_strs Union.
Why? Because it is validated as a dict in the json_or_int case. The behaviour seems strange that it attempts validating against any further items in the Union once the first one is satisfied.

Does the documentation for unions in Pydantic help?

Yes, thanks very much! I needed json_or_str: Json[Any] | str = Field(union_mode="left_to_right")

Sounds worth writing up as a self-answer to me.

Thanks to Karl for the link to the documentation for unions in Pydantic.
I needed union mode left to right. Pydantic defaults to smart mode which will look for the most exact match. In my case a str was a more exact match than parsing the string into a Json.
Here's the working code:
from typing import Any

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, Json


class FooStr(BaseModel):
    json_or_str: Json[Any] | str = Field(union_mode="left_to_right")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(type(FooStr(json_or_str='{"a": 1}').json_or_str))  # prints <class 'dict'>

